# To have a function triggered when up and down key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, addeventlistener, keycode

I want to have it so when the up or down key is pressed it triggers different functions. This is my code so far:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

    console.log("A Key has been pressed");

    /*Sets "key" variable to be the value of the key code of the key pressed*/
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

    /*checks if key pressed is the "up" key*/
    if (key === 38){
            functionOne();
            console.log("Up key was Pressed");
        }

    /*checks if key pressed is the "down" key*/     
    else if (key === 40){
            functionTwo();
            console.log("Down key was Pressed");
        }
    })
```

The console log displaying "A key has been pressed" activates whenever I press any key apart from the arrow keys, shift, alt, caps, tab and f1 - f12. What could be causing this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How have you verified that the event is firing? Put a console.log in the event callback itself - never assume it's firing. If it is, the next step is to check what the value of `key` is. Essential debugging.

Comment: Thank you that is good advice, I will add that and edit the question depending on the result.

Comment: What browser are you using to test this?

Comment: Chrome Web Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [keyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event instead.

> The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC, arrows) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use the [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) event instead, because it works for all keys.

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    console.log(key);
    if (key === 38){
        console.log("Up key was Pressed", key );
    }    
    else if (key === 40){
        console.log("Down key was Pressed", key );
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: what does the "e.preventDefault();" do?

Comment: Also, thanks for your answer but hasn't seemed to solve it

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` For example, this can be useful when: *Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form*, 
*Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL*

Comment: @HugoStiles *A pleasure to help you*